SwiftUI - Text Right Alignment in a Horizontal Scroll View
I have some code here simply trying to right align/trailing edge align a text view inside an HStack...no matter what I do, it wants to left align/leading edge align. What do I do?
struct RightAlignedScrollView: View {
    let text = "12345"

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Text(text)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
            }
            .padding(.trailing, 10) // Adds padding to avoid text sticking to the edge
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2)) // Background to visualize the frame
    }
}


See also ScrollView: content alignment issue

You could try this approach using a GeometryReader to force the text to be trailing, such as:
struct RightAlignedScrollView: View {
    let text = "12345"
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geom in
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text(text)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                }
                .padding(.trailing, 10)
                .frame(width: geom.size.width, alignment: .trailing)
            }
        }
        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
    }
}


The Spacer is not working, because it is inside a ScrollView. Views inside a ScrollView are shown at their ideal size and the ideal size of a Spacer is very small (10 points).
To fix, set .containerRelativeFrame on the HStack, after the padding:
HStack {
    Spacer()
    Text(text)
        .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
}
.padding(.trailing, 10)
.containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal, alignment: .trailing) //  HERE



Other suggestions:

The Spacer can be dropped, since it doesn't really work. However, this means you will probably want to use .horizontal padding, instead of just .trailing.

Without the Spacer, the HStack only contains the Text, so the HStack is now redundant. You could drop the HStack too and apply .containerRelativeFrame to the Text instead.

The .frame on the ScrollView is also redundant, because the ScrollView automatically uses the full width of the display.

The initializer that you are using for ScrollView is deprecated. To hide the scroll indicators, use the modifier .scrollIndicators instead.


Here is how the example could be modified:
ScrollView(.horizontal) {
    Text(text)
        .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
        .padding(.horizontal, 10)
        .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal, alignment: .trailing)
}
.scrollIndicators(.hidden)
.background(.gray.opacity(0.2))

